# Microsoft Dynamics CRM On-premises AD and claim based

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Can Dynamics `CRM` Customer Engagement On-Premises version 8 and version 9, support at the same time (on the same instance) AD authentication (on internal URL) and claim based authentication on `IFD`?
I didn't find anything about this in the documentation, and when I try to enable claim based authentication, AD authentication seems to disappear.